# Why is Django (3.0.6) looking in the wrong directory for admin static files?

Tags: python, django, admin

I have restructured my django project, and for some reason the django admin loads with no css applied and looking at the log it shows:

```
Django version 3.0.6, using settings 'config.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[16/May/2020 16:48:33] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1910
Not Found: /admin/login/static/admin/css/login.css
Not Found: /admin/login/static/admin/css/responsive.css
Not Found: /admin/login/static/admin/css/base.css
[16/May/2020 16:48:33] "GET /admin/login/static/admin/css/login.css HTTP/1.1" 404 4875
[16/May/2020 16:48:33] "GET /admin/login/static/admin/css/responsive.css HTTP/1.1" 404 4890
[16/May/2020 16:48:33] "GET /admin/login/static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 404 4872
[16/May/2020 16:48:34] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1910
Not Found: /admin/login/static/admin/css/login.css
Not Found: /admin/login/static/admin/css/base.css
Not Found: /admin/login/static/admin/css/responsive.css
[16/May/2020 16:48:34] "GET /admin/login/static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 404 4872
[16/May/2020 16:48:34] "GET /admin/login/static/admin/css/login.css HTTP/1.1" 404 4875
[16/May/2020 16:48:34] "GET /admin/login/static/admin/css/responsive.css HTTP/1.1" 404 4890
```

*"/admin/login/static/admin/css/"* is not a directory and I am confused. Project structure and settings files below.

```
<repository root>
│   │db.sqlite3
│   │manage.py
│   
│           
├───config
│   │   asgi.py
│   │   settings.py
│   │   urls.py
│   │   wsgi.py
│   │   __init__.py
│      
│   
│           
├───docs
└───project
    ├───media
    ├───products
    │   │   admin.py
    │   │   apps.py
    │   │   models.py
    │   │   tests.py
    │   │   urls.py
    │   │   views.py
    │   │   __init__.py
    │   │   
    │   ├───migrations
    │       │   0001_initial.py
    │       │   __init__.py
    │       │   
    │              
    │           
    ├───static
    │   └───admin
    │       ├───css
    │           │   autocomplete.css
    │           │   base.css
    │           │   changelists.css
    │           │   dashboard.css
    │           │   fonts.css
    │           │   forms.css
    │           │   login.css
    │           │   responsive.css
    │           │   responsive_rtl.css
    │           │   rtl.css
    │           │   widgets.css
    │              
    │                       
    ├───templates
    │       base.html
    │       index.html
```

**settings.py**

```
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path

# This is the <repository root>
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# This is the <project repository>
PROJECT_DIR = BASE_DIR / 'swiftr'

# Append to the system path
sys.path.append(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, PROJECT_DIR))

MEDIA_ROOT = PROJECT_DIR / 'media'

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = PROJECT_DIR / 'static'


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'f#&1x0!uyqn^hm(g67@_^o999tchl3aczwvtarj3p&u*9wj3sn'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'taggit',
    'products',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'config.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [PROJECT_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'config.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-gb'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

I have tried collectstatic and that is why it has created a static directory within the project directory. If you need to see anything else, please let me know.

Comment: Why you are not using recommended settings? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/ and

Comment: Hi, I'm reading 'Two Scoops of Django 1.11' in which it recommends this approach if you change the file structure like I have.

Comment: 'Two Scoops of Django 1.11' is old Django's current version is 3 and 'Two Scoops of Django 3.x is coming out soon too https://www.feldroy.com/products/two-scoops-of-django-3-x. With that in mind docs always refer better.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seemed to be the STATIC_URL. It required a backsplash before and after '/static/' once this was amended the CSS loaded.